# how do I turn an ES6 Proxy back into a plain object (POJO)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I'm using a library that turns things into ES6 Proxy objects, and another library that I think is choking because I'm passing it one of these (my code is a travesty, I know), and I couldn't figure out how to unProxy the Proxy object.

But I was just being dumb. Proxies can do anything!

Comment: Why is the library choking on your proxy? Please post (the relevant part of) the code of the library, and of your proxy, so that we can help you fix your handlers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Tried using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(proxyObj))` but that removes anything that cannot be stringified (like classes, functions, callback, etc...) which isn't good for my use case since I have some callback function declarations in my object and I want to see them as part of my object. However I found out that using the [Lodash cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) function does a real good job at converting a Proxy object into a POJO while keeping the object structure.

```js
convertProxyObjectToPojo(proxyObj) {
  return _.cloneDeep(proxyObj);
}
```

Comment: This appeals to me, since I generally trust lodash, and it hides all the confusing stuff. I'm no longer using whatever that library was that was messing me up, so I can't test the different answers. If anyone objects to my choosing this one as the official answer, let me know and I'll revisit.

Answer (score 37):

I find a hack. In my case, I can't control the creation of the proxy(mobx observable values). So the solution is:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(your.object))
```

Comment: smart :) sometimes things can be so simple, thank you!

Comment: Doesn't this end up losing some stuff? People seem to like it.

Comment: @Sigfried well, as was said in the accepted answer it is losing some stuff, but I guess the most common case when you don't have these kinds of properties in your object. I think it's only good as a debugging tool at least I was using it only with this purpose.


JSON.stringify({ key: undefined });
JSON.stringify({ key: Symbol() });
JSON.stringify({ key: function(){} });
// all will be converted to just "{}"

Comment: This isn not smart at all – you Dates will be messed up after parse and stringify

Comment: It's much slower than deep clone.

Comment: Don't do this, cause your dates will be messed up after this transform

Answer (score 14):

How about using the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)?

```
 const plainObject = { ...proxyObject };
```

Comment: Upvoted because it works for my situation but this only seems to remove the proxy on the 'root' of the object.

Comment: upvoted. this is the simplest way without using any library.

Comment: Doesn't work for nested `Proxy` (it's just a shallow copy), to copy/clone **entire** object recursively use [`_.cloneDeep()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use lodash The object.assign({},val) method is OK. But if the val contains nested objects they will be proxified. So it has to be done recursively like that:

```
function unproxify(val) {
    if (val instanceof Array) return val.map(unproxify)
    if (val instanceof Object) return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(Object.assign({},val)).map(([k,v])=>[k,unproxify(v)]))
    return val
}
```

In fact it is a deep clone function. I think that it does not work if val contains Map objects but you can modify the function for that following the same logic.

If you want to unproxify a Vue3 proxy, Vue3 provides a function : toRaw

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an accepted answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?

Comment: toRaw function does not return POJO object. It;s misunderstanding and a mistake in the docs. As you can see here It disables reacrivity using a flag and that's all. This misunderstanding is a source of bugs while working with Web Workers and Vue docs should be fixed ASAP. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/main/src/v3/reactivity/reactive.ts

Answer (score 5):

```
pp = new Proxy(
   {a:1},
   {
      get: function(target, prop, receiver) { 
             if(prop==='target') return target 
           }
   }
)
```

But that will only work if you can control creation of the proxy. It turns out to be even easier though:

```
pojo = Object.assign({}, proxyObj) // won't unwrap nested proxies though
```

**For readers who might like this answer, David Gilbertson's newer answer might be better. I personally prefer lodash clonedeep. And the most popular seems to be JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))**

Comment: This results in `{a: undefined}` rather than `{a: 1}`, if the `get` handler is still there. Otherwise, [`({...proxyObj})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) is even shorter.

Comment: Your `get` handler needs an `else` case where it behaves normally (i.e. `Reflect.get`) on non-`target` properties.

Comment: If one of you would like to add an answer, I'd be happy to delete my botched one.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @sigfried for the answer, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Here's a slightly more detailed version, using `Symbol` to avoid clashes with real prop names.

```js
const original = {foo: 'bar'};

const handler = {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (prop === Symbol.for('ORIGINAL')) return target;

    return Reflect.get(target, prop);
  }
};

const proxied = new Proxy(original, handler);

console.assert(original !== proxied);

const unproxied = proxied[Symbol.for('ORIGINAL')];

console.assert(original === unproxied);
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited mine to refer people to this then. It would be nice if someone summarized and compared the pro/cons of the different answers. Maybe I will someday if no one else does.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd use mobx util toJS() for this.

```
import { observable, toJS } from "mobx";

const observed = observable({ foo: 'bar' })

const obj = toJS(observed)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have access to the original target, the quickest way to convert a `Proxy` is to `assign` its values to a new plain `Object`:

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, proxy);
```

Or use a spreader:

```
const obj = { ...proxy };
```

**Example**

```js
const user = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: 'john.doe@example.com',
};

const handler = {
  get(target, property) {
    return target[property];
  }
};

const proxy = new Proxy(user, handler);

const a = Object.assign({}, proxy);
console.log(`Using Object.assign():`);
console.log(`Hello, ${a.firstName} ${a.lastName}!`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));

const s = { ...proxy };
console.log(`Using spreader:`);
console.log(`Hello, ${s.firstName} ${s.lastName}!`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: When I tried your two suggestions, it just creates a new object with the proxy inside of it, which doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Both examples were tested before being posted, so I've added an example to show the new objects output from each.

Answer (score 0):

In the unproxied object constructor, add `this.self=this`

Then make sure your get handler allows the `self` property to be returned and you are all set.  `proxiedMyObj.self===myObj //returns true`